# movieclip rescales strangely

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

```
var pic0ldr:Loader = new Loader();
var thumb0Req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("0.jpg");
pic0ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(evt:Event){onComplete(evt, "stgW","stgH")});
pic0ldr.load(thumb0Req);

function onComplete(event:Event,stgW,stgH):void {
this[stgW] = event.target.content.width;
this[stgH] = event.target.content.height;
placeem("stgW","stgH");
}

function placeem(stgW,stgH):void {

leftmask_mc.height = this["stgH"];
leftmask_mc.width = this["stgW"];
pic0ldr.y = -this["stgH"];
pic0ldr.x = -this["stgW"];

trace(leftmask_mc.width,leftmask_mc.height,pic0ldr.height,pic0ldr.width);//500 707 707 500


leftmask_mc.addChild(pic0ldr);  //strange resize

leftmask_mc.height = this["stgH"];//
leftmask_mc.width = this["stgW"]; // normal again, without 569.25 845.55 707 500

trace(leftmask_mc.width,leftmask_mc.height,pic0ldr.height,pic0ldr.width);
}
```

You may wonder why I need the width and height data to resize my movieclip but I load many pictures and I have to get the max height and width

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to be sure what your question is, since you don't actually ask one, but I guess the problem is this:

If you set width and height of a MovieClip, like your leftmask_mc, to other proportion than it originally had, it will be distorted. Any child you add to that MovieClip will also be distorted in the same way, since it becomes a part of that MovieClip.

Also, if leftmask_mc is intended to be used as a mask, you probably don't want to add the loaded image as a child of leftmask_mc. If you want leftmask_mc to mask the image, you should instead set the .mask property of the image (or of a DisplayObject containing the image) to leftmask_mc.

Comment: My question is in the code comment, I don' want to use it as a mask. What I do is set the mc size to that of the picture and load it on it with addChild, but after doing that the mc get bigger in size although I have defined it. after redefining it's normal again. As for the proportion width/height I don't think that's the case I gave it another width not that of the pic and it stilled added the same pixels to the height and some to the width

Comment: OK. Still a bit hard to determine what you are trying to do, and what is not working, I think, but I'll give it another try, If what you want is simply to use leftmask_mc as a holder for the loaded image, you don't need to set height and width to the same as the image. When you add the image as a child, leftmask_mc will automatically take on the size of the image (the size of its content).

Answer (score 0):

Really have no idea what you are asking in your question.
But I will tell you, your code sample is horrendous, you are all over the place with functions and even using nameless functions.

```
leftmask_mc.height = this["stgH"];
leftmask_mc.width = this["stgW"];
pic0ldr.y = -this["stgH"];
pic0ldr.x = -this["stgW"];

trace(leftmask_mc.width,leftmask_mc.height,pic0ldr.height,pic0ldr.width);//500 707 707 500

// this is your problem when you pic0ldr, pic0ldr is is set to a NEGATIVE X and Y Which will cause leftmask to resize that amount
leftmask_mc.addChild(pic0ldr);  //strange resize
```

Again you need to reword your question and rework your code so it is legible to a point where we can understand it